# Increase F# map insertion performance

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, f#

I am currently doing some tests on F# maps vs C# dictionaries. I realize they are quite different implementation wise but they do fill the same sort of use for their respective languages.

I have designed a simple test to check the insertion times due to the F# map being immutable thus it has to create an entirely new map for each insertion. I was wondering just how much of a hit that is.

Test is as follows:

```
 //F# 
 module Test = 
    let testMapInsert () = 
        let sw = Stopwatch()
        let rec fillMap endIdx curr map =
            if curr = endIdx then 
                map 
            else 
                fillMap endIdx (curr + 1) (map |> Map.add curr curr)
        sw.Start ()
        let q = fillMap 100000000 Map.empty
        sw.Stop ()
        printfn "%A" sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

 //C#
 class Program
    {
        static void Test(int x) {
            var d = new Dictionary<int,int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                d.Add(i,i);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Test(10000000);
            sw.Stop();
            System.Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            //FSHARP.Test.testMapInsert(); f# function called in c#.

        }
    }
```

Doing 10 million element insertions with this yields the following times measured in ms:

```
C#: 332

F#: 13605
```

I figured the C# dictionary would be a fair bit faster but that is quite the difference.

Is there a way to speed up the F# dictionary for this sort of use-case? Or is this just the way it is and the F# map has a trade-off with performance in these situations for thread safety?

Comment: Just F# Map is an immutable datastructures based around Red/Black Trees compared to mutable dictionaries in C# that is based around hash tables. One do expect some performance difference from that but from my experience the biggest difference in F# Map comes from the slow generic comparison function. It's slow because it's generic. I was experimenting with a map implementation that allowed custom generic comparision functions but it didn't work out well enough to do a PR to F# core.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the difference is not based on the distinction between C# and F#, but based on the distinction between an immutable tree-based map and hashtable-based mutable dictionary.

Using `#time`, I get the following performance in F# interactive:

```
#time 
// Immutable tree-based F# map (~14 sec)
let mutable map = Map.empty
for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
  map <- Map.add i i map

// Mutable hashtable-based .NET dictionary (~0.3 sec)
let dict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_, _>()
for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
  dict.Add(i, i)
```

The interesting question is - can you make immutable F# map faster? In principle, you can build a map faster if you know that you are working with an already sorted array. The F# map does not have any operation that would let you do this, but it could be added.

When I define my own Map type that shares the interanl structure with the F# map:

```
type MapTree<'Key, 'Value when 'Key : comparison > = 
  | MapEmpty 
  | MapOne of 'Key * 'Value
  | MapNode of 'Key * 'Value * MapTree<'Key, 'Value> *  MapTree<'Key, 'Value> * int
```

I can then define `ofSortedArray` operation:

```
let height = function
  | MapEmpty -> 0
  | MapOne _ -> 1
  | MapNode(_, _, _, _, h) -> h

let rec ofSortedArray (data:_[]) i j = 
  if i = j then MapOne(data.[i])
  elif i > j then MapEmpty 
  else 
    let m = i + (j - i) / 2
    let l, r = ofSortedArray data i (m - 1), ofSortedArray data (m + 1) j
    let k, v = data.[m]
    MapNode(k, v, l, r, 1 + (max (height l) (height r)))
```

This is still nowhere near as efficient as a mutable hashtable, but I get the following:

```
// Immutable tree-based F# map, using sorted array 
let arr = [| for i in 0 .. 10000000 -> i, i |] // ~1 sec
let map = ofSortedArray arr 0 10000000         // ~3 sec
```

If you actually wanted to use this, you would need your own version of the F# map - or you could send a pull request to the F# core libraries adding support for something like this!